# Simple PHP Array - How do I get the results to a variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the results of an array and move them to a `$variable`.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
$total_days_month = date('t'); // total days this month

// add "$currentday" day number to an array until $currentday<=$total_days_month
$days_array = array();
for ($currentday=1; $currentday<=$total_days_month; $currentday++) {
if ($total_days_month > $currentday)
{
array_push($days_array,"'$currentday',");
}
else
{
array_push($days_array,"'$currentday'");
}
}
// now transfer the array content to a $variable

$variable = ????

?>
```

`$variable` content must be `'1', '2', '3', '4' ........ '31'`

Comment: `$variable = $days_array;`

Comment: Instead of this: http://screencast.com/t/nd6BhnDXJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$variable = implode("','", $days_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$total_days_month = date('t'); // total days this month

// add "$currentday" day number to an array until $currentday<=$total_days_month
$days_array = array();
for ($currentday=1; $currentday<=$total_days_month; $currentday++) {
 if ($total_days_month > $currentday){
    array_push($days_array,"'$currentday',");
 }else{
    array_push($days_array,"'$currentday',");
 }
}

// now transfer the array content to a $variable

$variable = implode(',', $days_array);
```